# Java send notification to all classes

Tags: java, notifications

I'm pretty new whith Java and trying to write an app that open/close a JDialog on event.
When event is INCOMING it open a new JDialog, if event is ABANDONED it should close the proper opened JDialog.

The listener can receive severals INCOMNIG and opens a new JDialog setting a unique id.

When listener receive the ABANDONED event all opened JDialog should receive a notification with the ID and the the one with that id should dispose itself.

Anyone can point me to the right direction?

```
public class WorkItemStateChangedListener implements SessionListener {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event ev) {
        WorkItem.StateChanged sc = (WorkItem.StateChanged) ev;
        WorkItem wi = sc.getWorkItem();
        if (sc.getState() == WorkItem.State.INCOMING) {
                    OpenDialogWithid(wi.getId());
        }
        else if (sc.getState() == WorkItem.State.ABANDONED) {
            DisposeDialogWithid(wi.getId());
        }

    }

    private void OpenDialogWithid(String id) {
        JDialog _dialog = new MyDialog();
        _dialog.id = id;
    }

    private void DisposeDialogWithid(String id) {

        //This method shuld notify to all opened dialog to close the one that match the id

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using some form of cache, where you store all the `JDialog`s:

```
private final Map<String, JDialog> openedDialogs = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

I used a `synchronizedMap`, because you could have interferance between mutliple threads.

This can then be populated:

```
private void OpenDialogWithid(String id) {
    JDialog _dialog = new MyDialog();
    _dialog.id = id;
    openedDialogs.put(id, _dialog);
}
```

And cleared:

```
private void DisposeDialogWithid(String id) {
    if(openedDialogs.containsKey(id)){
        JDialog _dialog = openedDialogs.remove(id);
        // close the dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a map to keep track of your JDialog:

```java
public class WorkItemStateChangedListener implements SessionListener {

private final Map<String, JDialog> dialogMap = new HashMap();

@Override
public void onEvent(Event ev) {
    WorkItem.StateChanged sc = (WorkItem.StateChanged) ev;
    WorkItem wi = sc.getWorkItem();
    if (sc.getState() == WorkItem.State.INCOMING) {
                OpenDialogWithid(wi.getId());
    }
    else if (sc.getState() == WorkItem.State.ABANDONED) {
        DisposeDialogWithid(wi.getId());
    }

}

private void OpenDialogWithid(String id) {
    JDialog _dialog = new MyDialog();
    _dialog.id = id;
    dialogMap.put(id,_dialog);
}

private void DisposeDialogWithid(String id) {
    if (dialogMap.containsKey(id)){
       dialogMap.remove(id).close(); //or the appropriate close method
     }

}
}
```

Comment: The id is a `String` your map is defined as `Map<Integer,JDialog>` so `dialogMap.get(id)` would result in a compile time error. The 2nd thing i'd like to mention is, that `Map#remove(K key)`  returns the removed item (is there is any) so you could shorten the code down to simply: `dialogMap.remove(id).close();`. This would increase readabilty since it's not redudant. A third notable improvement would be to let the compiler interfer the type of the map: `Map<Integer,JDialog> map = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Indeed this code is not clean, I just wanted to propose using a Map. The use of a synchronizedMap proposed by Lino should be better anyway in this context...

Comment: still major flaws should be [edited out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51537571/edit) :)

Comment: Done. I even forgot a semicolon ^^